# How do I update a specific edge property using Gremlin/Titan/TinkerPop3?

Tags: titan, gremlin, tinkerpop3

#### The goal

I have a simple enough task to accomplish: Set the weight of a specific edge property. Take this scenario as an example:

[image: Example Graph Structure]

What I would like to do is update the value of `weight`.

**Additional Requirements**

- If the edge does not exist, it should be created.
- There may only exist at most one edge of the same type between the two nodes (i.e., there can't be multiple "votes_for" edges of `type` "eat" between Joey and Pizza.
- The task should be solved using the [Java API of Titan](http://titan.thinkaurelius.com/javadoc/1.0.0/) (which includes Gremlin as part of [TinkerPop 3](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/)).

---

#### What I know

I have the following information:

- The [Vertex](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/3.2.2/core/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/structure/Vertex.html) labeled "user"
- The edge label `votes_for`
- The value of the edge property `type` (in this case, "eat")
- The value of the property `name` of the vertex labeled "meal" (in this case "pizza"), and hence also its [Vertex](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/3.2.2/core/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/structure/Vertex.html).

#### What I thought of

I figured I would need to do something like the following:

1. Start at the Joey vertex
2. Find all outgoing edges (which should be at most 1) labeled `votes_for` having `type` "eat" and an outgoing vertex labeled "meal" having `name` "pizza".
3. Update the `weight` value of the edge.

This is what I've messed around with in code:

```
//vertex is Joey in this case
g.V(vertex.id())
    .outE("votes_for")
    .has("type", "eat")
    //... how do I filter by .outV so that I can check for "pizza"?
    .property(Cardinality.single, "weight", 0.99);
    //... what do I do when the edge doesn't exist?
```

As commented in code there are still issues. Would explicitly specifying a Titan schema help? Are there any helper/utility methods I don't know of? Would it make more sense to have several `vote_for` labels instead of one label + `type` property, like `vote_for_eat`?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are on the right track. Check out the [vertex steps documentation](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#vertex-steps).

Label the edge, then traverse from the edge to the vertex to check, then jump back to the edge to update the property.

```
g.V(vertex.id()).
  outE("votes_for").has("type", "eat").as("e").
  inV().has("name", "pizza").
  select("e").property("weight", 0.99d).
  iterate()
```

Full Gremlin console session:

```
gremlin> Titan.version()
==>1.0.0
gremlin> Gremlin.version()
==>3.0.1-incubating
gremlin> graph = TitanFactory.open('inmemory'); g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[standardtitangraph[inmemory:[127.0.0.1]], standard]
gremlin> vertex = graph.addVertex(T.label, 'user', 'given_name', 'Joey', 'family_name', 'Tribbiani')
==>v[4200]
gremlin> pizza = graph.addVertex(T.label, 'meal', 'name', 'pizza')
==>v[4104]
gremlin> votes = vertex.addEdge('votes_for', pizza, 'type', 'eat', 'weight', 0.8d)
==>e[1zh-38o-4r9-360][4200-votes_for->4104]
gremlin> g.E(votes).valueMap(true)
==>[label:votes_for, weight:0.8, id:2rx-38o-4r9-360, type:eat]
gremlin> g.V(vertex.id()).outE('votes_for').has('type','eat').as('e').inV().has('name','pizza').select('e').property('weight', 0.99d).iterate(); g.E(votes).valueMap(true)
==>[label:votes_for, weight:0.99, id:2rx-38o-4r9-360, type:eat]
```

*Would explicitly specifying a Titan schema help?*

If you wanted to start from the `Joey` node without having a reference to the `vertex` or its `id`, this would be a good use case for a Titan [composite index](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/indexes.html#_composite_index). The traversal would start with:

```
g.V().has("given_name", "Joey")
```

*Are there any helper/utility methods I don't know of?*

In addition to the [TinkerPop reference documentation](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/), there are several tutorials that you can read through:

1. [Getting Started](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/tutorials/getting-started/)
2. [The Gremlin Console](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/tutorials/the-gremlin-console/)
3. [Recipes](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/)

*Would it make more sense to have several vote_for labels instead of one label + type property, like vote_for_eat?*

Depends on what your graph model or query patterns are, but more granular labels like `vote_for_eat` can work out fine. You can pass multiple edge labels on the traversal step:

```
g.V(vertex.id()).outE('vote_for_eat', 'vote_for_play', 'vote_for_sleep')
```

**Update**

*There may only exist at most one edge of the same type between the two nodes*

You can use the Titan schema to help with this, specifically define an [edge label with multiplicity](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/schema.html#_edge_label_multiplicity) `ONE2ONE`. An exception will be thrown if you create more than one `votes_for_eat` between `Joey` and `pizza`.

Answer (score 6):

Jason already answered nearly all of your questions. The only aspect missing is:

> If the edge does not exist, it should be created.

So I'll try to answer this point with a slightly different query. This query adds a new edge if it doesn't exist already and then updates / adds the `weight` property:

```java
g.V(vertex.id()).outE('votes_for').has('type', 'eat')
    .where(__.inV().hasLabel('meal').has('name','pizza')) // filter for the edge to update
    .tryNext()                                            // select the edge if it exists
    .orElseGet({g.V(vertex.id()).next()
        .addEdge('votes_for', g.V(pizzaId).next(), 'type', 'eat')}) // otherwise, add the edge
    .property('weight', 0.99)               // finally, update / add the 'weight' property
```

Comment: Awesome, +1. That takes care of all requirements in one elegant query. Thanks!